# What does "mod 2" mean in these multi-level inverter switching equations?

Tags: inverter, power-electronics, power-engineering

I am working through a paper that discusses the design of a multi-level inverter to connect photovoltaic arrays to the grid. It uses 4 PV modules (only two are shown in the design image below, but it is expandable) along with an H-bridge to produce 31 voltage levels. These are used to produce a modified sine wave with low THD:
[image: Proposed inverter design]

The scheme for switching Q1 - Q4 uses a reference voltage:
V_ref(t) = V_max*sin(wt + delta_ref)
[image]

The authors given equations for calculating the switch signals, which include "mod 2":
[image: Switching equations for Q1 - Q4]

I am aware of the usual meaning of "m mod n" as "the remainder left over when m is divided by n". This doesn't seem to work here at all!

**Can anybody tell me how the given equations are able to generate the switching signals?**:
[image: Switching signal graphs]

Comment: Modulo 2 is the remainder when an integer is divide by 2. For example 7 modulo 2 = 1, since 7/2 = 3 remainder 1. Modulo 2 is used in digital systems because dividing any positive integer by 2 will give a remainder of either 1 or zero

Comment: Can you give a link to the paper, so we can get a bit more context around the equations? (In particular what the function $$V_{ref}$$ does.)

Comment: Here is the paper, but it is behind a pay wall (perhaps available through your own institution): [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038092X10003038). V_ref is a reference sine wave with the same frequency as the desired output AC voltage. I understand the usual remainder usage of modulus, but in this case V_ref is not an integer. It also may never get above 1, depending on the chosen value of V_max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) of the value with 2. It's used to isolate the individual quantization bits in the digital representation of the wave.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How does it work to generate the switching signals in this case?

Comment: The level modules act as a DAC in order to generate the sine wave.

Comment: I see a bit better now. For a sinusoidal V_ref (expressed as floating point value), simply taking V_ref mod 2 does not result in a nice 0,1,0,1,... sequence. I'm able to get something by scaling V_ref to +/- 15 and rounding it to the nearest integer value. That way, V_ref is an integer between -15 and +15. Now when I take V_ref mod 2 the value is always the 0 or 1 I want. These are then used for the switching values. Thanks!